# How do I know if my Apple Push Services is correct?

Tags: marketing-cloud, salesforcemobilesdk-ios, mobilesdk, mobilepush-ios

I am using Salesforce Marketing Cloud to push notification by using Mobile Push SDK. Recently, I have to renew my Certificate for some reasons. I follow the instruction and create a Provisioning Profile and Apple Push Services for my app again. However, I don't receive notification this time.

1. My Mac is not the one that creates the main iOS Distribution Certificate, so I have to ask for the main cert and key from my teammate in order to build my source code. I use my CSR to create Apple Push Services instead of his. Does that effect creating Apple Push Services?
2. I download the new Apple Push Services. In Keychain Access, I select the "My Certificates" tab. I click at my iOS Push Services. Then, I see both the cert and the private key. How do I export it?

   - export only the cert. (I usually use this option)
   - *export both the cert and the private key*. (edit. this option can't be imported to SFMC)
3. Is there a way to debug and see what cause pushing notification issue?

Comment: Did you have any success here? When exporting your certificate, you select the certificate (which _does_ contain the private key) and export - that will form the proper p12 file for adding to SFMC.

Comment: If you've added the iOS distribution cert/key to your keychain, you should have no trouble with creating the push certificate.

Comment: I succeed importing p12 file to SFMC. Now, I understand what the tutorial and you say. I shouldn't select both cert and private key and export them at the same time. I should select just the cert (which contains the private key) instead. However, there is no device id comes to database Exacttarget. My developer just says that the problem should be the cert because he uses the same code which works fine with another app (only different things are bundle id, access token, app id and certification). Now, I don't know where the issue is.